# Current date insertion in edit mode of Grideview in asp.net framework

Tags: asp.net

Sir, I am a new learner of asp.net and trying to develop some small data driven webpages in asp.net which were earlier developed in classic asp nad working fine till now. But change of our server I am unable to publish my old webpages in classic asp. Sir, in classic asp,  current date could be inserted easliy in update page but I am unable to do so in asp.net.  Here is my code and I want to put current date automatically in Updation_date field in Gridview editmode while customer update the data in other fields.  Sir please help.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView runat="server" id="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataKeyNames="ID" AllowSorting="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:commandfield ShowDeleteButton="False" ShowEditButton="True" ShowSelectButton="False">
            </asp:commandfield>
            <asp:boundfield DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ReadOnly="True" InsertVisible="False" SortExpression="ID" Visible="False">
            </asp:boundfield>
            <asp:boundfield DataField="acc_date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" HeaderText="Date of Accident" SortExpression="acc_date">
            </asp:boundfield>
            <asp:boundfield DataField="Rly" HeaderText="Rly" SortExpression="Rly">
            </asp:boundfield>
            <asp:boundfield DataField="Division" HeaderText="Division" SortExpression="Division">
            </asp:boundfield>
            <asp:boundfield DataField="Involving" HeaderText="Involving" SortExpression="Involving">
            </asp:boundfield>
            <asp:boundfield DataField="Findings" HeaderText="Findings" SortExpression="Findings">
            </asp:boundfield>
            <asp:boundfield DataField="Responsibility" HeaderText="Responsibility" SortExpression="Responsibility">
            </asp:boundfield>
            <asp:boundfield DataField="Action" HeaderText="Action" SortExpression="Action">
            </asp:boundfield>
            <asp:boundfield DataField="updation_date" HeaderText="updation_date" SortExpression="updation_date">
            </asp:boundfield>
            <asp:boundfield DataField="Class" HeaderText="Class" SortExpression="Class" Visible="false">
            </asp:boundfield>
            <asp:boundfield DataField="Year" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="Year" Visible="false">
            </asp:boundfield>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:AccessDataSource runat="server" ID="AccessDataSource1" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [accident] WHERE [ID] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [accident] ([acc_date], [Rly], [Division], [Involving], [Findings], [Responsibility], [Action], [updation_date], [Class], [Year]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [accident] SET [acc_date] = ?, [Rly] = ?, [Division] = ?, [Involving] = ?, [Findings] = ?, [Responsibility] = ?, [Action] = ?, [updation_date] = ?, [Class] = ?, [Year] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?" DataFile="unusual.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [accident]WHERE ([Rly] = ?) ORDER BY [acc_date] DESC">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
        <asp:parameter DefaultValue="CR" Name="Rly" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:parameter Name="acc_date" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Rly" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Division" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Involving" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Findings" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Responsibility" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Action" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="updation_date" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Class" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Year" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:parameter Name="acc_date" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Rly" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Division" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Involving" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Findings" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Responsibility" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Action" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="updation_date" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Class" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Year" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle the RowEditing event.  You'll have access to the fields of the row being edited.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, remove the `BoundField` for `updation_date` from GridView's columns. Sir, after that subscribe for `AccessDataSource1` `Updating` event and add following code to that event handler: `e.Command.Parameters["updation_date"].Value = DateTime.Now;`. Sir, do the same with the `Inserting` event. Sir, you may use the same method for handling both events, sir.

Added: if you want to show `updation_date` in a grid, change it from `BoundField` to `TemplateField` as below:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Updated Date" SortExpression="updation_date" >
     <ItemTemplate>
          <%# Eval("updation_date") %>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <EditItemTemplate>
          <%# DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
     </EditItemTemplate>
     <InsertItemTemplate>
          <%# DateTime.Now.ToString() %>
     </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: This error found - Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdatedEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Command' and no extension method 'Command' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdatedEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Did you read my answer? Why you subscribe to GridView's `Updated` event though I'm advise subscribe to **SqlDataSource**'s `Updating` event?

Comment: Sir, if possible please write complete coading for SqlDataSource's Updating event. I am not familier with event handlers. I will be highly thankfull to you.